# How to Use UILabel instance Method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uilabel

As I m new to iphone programming,
and i have also done little bit of coding in it.
I never gone through the apple's documentation.
But now I just started reading it,and I found some methodes very hard for me ,
I am feeling hard to implement this,as SOF been a key for my coding ,
that's why I am asking this.Please tell me how to use UILabel class's
 instance method

```
– (CGRect)textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:
– (void)drawTextInRect:
```

if possible provide some code,thanks in advance,expecting your help.:)

Comment: This question is way too broad. You are almost asking for a tutorial on objective-c. Tell us exactly what you are trying to accomplish and then we can help you.

Comment: @sosborn i m just asking what can i do via using these methodes,thanks for the responce.

Comment: Given the names of the methods and what the docs say about them, what do you think they do?

Comment: @sosborn i want to use – (void)drawTextInRect: for my UILabel,i am not getting what docs says about them.how can i use it?

Comment: As was asked earlier: "Tell us exactly what you are trying to accomplish and then we can help you."

Comment: i want  to draw the receiver’s text (or its shadow) in the specified rectangle.by using 

- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
    and why this method is overridden.

Comment: That should have been your original question. Anyway, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The method "textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:" returns the drawing rectangle for the label’s text.

Syntax:
(CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds limitedToNumberOfLines:(NSInteger)numberOfLines

bounds
The bounding rectangle of the receiver.
numberOfLines
The maximum number of lines to use for the label. The value 0 indicates there is no maximum number of lines and that the rectangle should encompass all of the text

This method should not be called directly, bUt it should be overridden by the sub class.

It can be overlaoded in the following way:

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds limitedToNumberOfLines (NSInteger)numberOfLines
{
return CGRectInset(bounds, MARGIN, MARGIN);
}

- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
[super drawTextInRect: CGRectInset(self.bounds, MARGIN, MARGIN)];
}
```

Comment: [a link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UILabel/textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:)

Comment: thanks for ur responce!but answer what i asked above in comments,if u know!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to draw the text in a specific rectangle you need to subclass UILabel and override `– (CGRect)textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:`. Just remember to use your subclass instead of UILabel.

For example, let's say I want to draw text only on the left half of the label:

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds limitedToNumberOfLines:(NSInteger)numberOfLines {
   //Original method returns the bounds, so let's find the left half of the bounds
   CGRect leftHalfRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height);
   return leftHalfRect;
}
```

Because this method now returns left half rect of the bounds, you text will only draw in the left half rect.

Comment: It may be little strange ,but please explain if possible,If i have a label  in one view controller class then how to implement this method for text.Please explain little brief,thanks for your help and response.

Comment: You should take some time to read some Objective-C tutorials, especially with respect to subclassing. It is a core concept and it is clear that you are not comfortable with it.